# Угол между шарами одинаковой массы после столкновения (упругого)

Tags: физика, 2d

Симулирую столкновения шаров в 2D, сделал столкновения о стенки, теперь встал перед проблемой определения угла между ними после нецентрального удара. Пусть векторы скоростей шаров соответственно равны `v1`, и `v2`. Иза за одинаковой массы, как объясняется в [матчасти](http://www.physics.ru/courses/op25part1/content/chapter1/section/paragraph21/theory.html#.Vddoj31LWmM), следует, что шары после столкновения, в этом случае просто обменяются скоростями, а угол между ними **всегда** будет прямым (как я понял, это угол между направляющими линиями(векторами) шаров после удара). Мне не понятно почему говорится ВСЕГДА этот угол будет прямым ??? Везде даются картинки и пояснения когда этот угол выходит точно в 90 градусов.
Сомневаясь до отчаяния, нашёл таки пример удара когда угол не прямой. Например [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajn9K.jpg) можно построить подобный удар. На рисунках показаны результаты до и после удара.

До удара:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]
после

Так что же тут происходит ?? Какой тут угол будет всегда прямым ?? Я не вижу тут никаких прямых углов! Что я не понимаю ?? Поясните пожалуйста поподрбней.

Comment: Вам же там написано, что это частный случай, когда шар стоит а другой в него ударяется. А вообще еще немного выше написано что любую систему можно привести к такому случаю когда в момент удара будем считать что один шар стоит. При этом потом с помощью матрицы преобразований получаем скорости и векторы скоростей.

Comment: @binliz про частный случай ясно, непонятно что будет происходит когда оба шара двигаются и сталкиваются друг с другом

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В моём понимании задачки подобного рода решаются очень просто.
[image: Диаграмма абсолютно упругого удара]
На рисунке вверху два изображения. До удара (слева) и после удара (справа). 
Исходные вектора скоростей взяты произвольно. 
Кратко разъясню суть.

1. Шары как-то движутся.
2. Шары ударяются. В момент удара шары деформируются в месте контакта.
3. Энергия деформации на все 100% переходит в кинетическую энергию шаров.

Работает закон сохранения импульса и закон сохранения энергии. Что касается импульса - это величина векторная. Поэтому её(как и скорость) можно разложить на две составляющие. Ось ОХ совмещается с линией, которая соединяет центры шаров. Ось OY ⊥ OX.

Вертикальная(OY) составляющая импульса на удар влияния не оказывает. Поэтому она остается неизменной. А горизонтальными составляющими импульса шары просто обмениваются. Итого:

- V2OY = V2*OY
- V1OY = V1*OY
- V2OX = V1*OX
- V1OX = V2*OX

А под 90 градусов шары разлетятся в случае если один из шаров неподвижен.

Comment: Как все оказывается просто, если оси правильно расположить.