# Нецентральный 2D удар 2х шаров с коэффициентом упругости

Tags: физика

Есть 2 шара про которые мы знаем все.
Их запускают под углами a и b со скоростями v1 и v2.
Как рассчитать новые скорости и углы, под которыми шары разлетятся после нецентрального столкновения с коэффициентом упругости k.

Comment: мы ж программисты. Зачем коэфициент упругости? И что это такое? Может, модуль упругости?

Comment: @Igor Коэффициент упругости - величина лежащая от 0..1, где крайние значения обозначают абсолютно неупругий и абсолютно упругий удары

Comment: @user277248 Ну и что коэффициент `k` означает **физически**? А вообще задача решается однозначно для неупругого соударения, для упругого - появляется неоднозначность. Например, при упругом соударении одного шарика с таким же покоящимся варианты могут быть самые разные - только и того, что разлетятся они под 90 градусов :) - но куда именно какой - просто так не скажешь, нужна, мягко говоря, очень серьезная физика...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Угол между шарами одинаковой массы после столкновения (упругого)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444249/%d0%a3%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: Я всё пояснил ранее здесь. [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444249)